# SSRS 2016 web page missing layout view not showing tiles and list

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS 2016 web page missing layout view not showing tiles and list. Have looked around and could not find much about it. Branding is not used. Few other SSRS link configured similarily are not having this issue. Has anyone come around this kind of issue with SSRS 2016

[image: SSRS 2016 web page missing layout view not showing tiles and list]

Comment: What browser are you using?  IE 11 has issues with SSRS 2016.

Comment: I tried with IE as well as well as Google Chrome. Having same issues in both